# Trying to have redshift reuse compiled code on where-in style queries

Tags: caching, query-optimization, amazon-redshift

As discussed [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=459005), redshift compiles queries on the first execution, and then reuses this compiled code for similar subsequent queries. This results in the first query being slow (3 to 10 of seconds), and the following similar ones quite fast (80 to 200ms). These are the numbers I have observed on a small cluster with a small-ish dataset (1-5M rows), others have a similar experience.

In [this article](https://medium.com/@pingram/redshift-code-compilation-977143576e89):

> These are the things that [didn't] cause a re-compilation:
>
> - Changing the quantity of student_ids in the WHERE clause by less than 10%

I have a similar query where I make heavy use of `WHERE ... IN(...)`, (populated by a multiselect field in the UI) and this cause every query that uses those filter to be much slower, because redshift has to recompile those queries. In my case, > 90% of the time, changing a single value in the `WHERE IN` forces redshift to recompile the query.

And because the combinations of every filters are very large (I have about ~10 filters, so about `10!`), warming up the query compilation cache as in the previous article is not really an option.

What are the strategies available so that redshift uses the compiled code for this slyle of query (maybe rewriting the query in a different style so that cache warming is a possibility?)

Comment: I don't suppose you've managed to solve this problem since you asked the question? We're experiencing similar difficulties in our Redshift instance.

Comment: @MikeTheLiar On this particular problem, I ended up using redshift in background aggregation jobs. The aggregated tables were written in a normal postgres db (with RDS via the DBLink extention). DBLink lets you write a single query selecting from redshift and inserting into RDS. The query is executed on the RDS cluster. The RDS tables are then indexed with normal PG indexes and the user-facing or API code uses those tables, so this sidesteps the caching issue.